# How to detect if a file is hidden

Tags: bash, files

I have written this code as part of some coursework, where we have to create a recursive file counter without using the find, du or -R commands. This appears to work but always returns hiddenfilecounter as 0. Is there any particular reason this is not working.

```
#!/bin/sh
shopt -s dotglob
directoryCounter=0
fileCounter=0
hiddenDirectoryCounter=0
hiddenFileCounter=0
listAllFiles() 
  {
   local dir=$1
   local file
   local bn=$(basename $dir)


   for file in "$dir"/*; do
     if [[ $bn == .* ]]; then
     let hiddenDirectoryCounter+=1
     listAllFiles "$file"
   elif [[ -f $file &&  "$file" == ^. ]]; then
     ls -l $file
     let hiddenFileCounter+=1
   elif [[ -f $file ]];then
     ls -l $file
     let fileCounter+=1
   elif [[ -d $file ]]; then
     listAllFiles "$file"
     let directoryCounter+=1
        fi
  done
} 
listAllFiles $1
echo File found: $fileCounter
echo Directories found: $directoryCounter
echo Hidden directories found: $hiddenDirectoryCounter
echo Hidden files found: $hiddenFileCounter
```

Comment: How would I fix this? I thought this was fixed by including `shopt -s dotglob`

Comment: @JoshuaTwaites, shopt -s dotglob should do the job. Please note that there are no hidden files on 'normal' unix filesystems, `ls` and and standard shell globbing don't include filenames with dots, but e.g. find does include them. This is not the same as hidden files based on attributed like you have on VFAT and NTFS partitions.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a few things wrong here. First, you are running `/bin/sh` when you actually want to run `/bin/bash`.

Now, the part of your script that checks for hidden files is

```
elif [[ -f $file &&  "$file" == ^. ]]; then
```

If you run your script as `foo.sh /home/foo`, each `$file` will begin with `/home/foo` so not even hidden files will begin with dots. In addition, you can't use `^` with `==`, it matches the beginning anyway (see [here](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/comparison-ops.html)).

Anyway, a working implementation of your script would be

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s dotglob
directoryCounter=0
fileCounter=0
hiddenDirectoryCounter=0
hiddenFileCounter=0
listAllFiles() 
  {
   local dir=$1
   local file
   local bn="$(basename -- "$dir")"


   for file in "$dir"/*; do
       ## Use ..* so you don't count the current dir (.) as hidden
       if [[ $bn == .?* ]]; then
        let hiddenDirectoryCounter+=1
        listAllFiles "$file"
       ## Match only the filename, not the whole path      
       elif [[ -f $file &&  "$(basename "$file")" == .* ]]; then
        let hiddenFileCounter+=1
       elif [[ -f "$file" ]];then
        let fileCounter+=1
       elif [[ -d "$file" ]]; then
        listAllFiles "$file"
        let directoryCounter+=1
       fi
  done
} 
listAllFiles $1
echo File found: $fileCounter
echo Directories found: $directoryCounter
echo Hidden directories found: $hiddenDirectoryCounter
echo Hidden files found: $hiddenFileCounter
```

However, that is not a very good way of doing it, you can't deal with more than one directory as input, more importantly, you only check if `$bn` is a hidden directory, never `$file` which means you will never find more than one hidden directory and you are making it unnecessarily complicated. You could greatly simplify by using `globstar`. I would write this like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
shopt -s dotglob

## globstar causes ** to match all files and directories
## recursively.
shopt -s globstar 

for dir in "$@"; do
    for file in "$dir"/**; do
      if [[ -f $file &&  "$(basename "$file")" == .* ]]; then
         let hiddenFileCounter+=1
      elif [[ -d $file &&  "$(basename "$file")" == .?* ]]; then
         let hiddenDirectoryCounter+=1
      elif [[ -f $file ]] ; then
         let fileCounter+=1
      elif [[ -d $file ]] ; then
         let directoryCounter+=1
      fi
    done
done

echo Files found: $fileCounter
echo Directories found: $directoryCounter
echo Hidden directories found: $hiddenDirectoryCounter
echo Hidden files found: $hiddenFileCounter
```

Comment: This works wonderfully, thank you. However if you put `..*` it doesn't work but `.*` does and it still doesn't detect the current directory

Comment: No, `[[ $bn = pattern ]]` is one of the rare places where you don't need quotes. You do need `bn="$(basename -- "$dir")"` though.

Comment: `..*` matches files that start with `..`, you probably meant `.?*`

Comment: The whole logic doesn't make sense anyway.

Comment: @JoshuaTwaites see updated answer.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas, could you please clarify why the command substitution on the right hand side of the assignment should be quoted? Thanks!

Comment: @DimitreRadoulov, it's not needed in `ksh` and `bash` but it is in all other shells that have a `local` _builtin_. Quoting doesn't harm.

Comment: On some systems, `sh` **is** `bash`.

Comment: @Totor yes, but invoking it with the name `sh` changes its behavior. See the INVOCATION section of `man bash`: "If  bash  is  invoked  with  the name sh, it tries to mimic the startup behavior of historical versions of sh".

Comment: Sure but the `[[ ... ]]` syntax still works in that case apparently...

Comment: @Totor ok, but not if `sh` is a symlink to `dash` and I don't know how the `shopt` options will work either. In any case, it is not safe to assume that `sh` is a link to `bash`, it isn't on Debian for Ubuntu or example.

Comment: I agree, I was only questioning your affirmation: "`sh` does not recognize `[[ ]]` format".

Comment: @Totor fair point, I have removed that sentence. I _did_ have problems on my system but here, `sh` points to `dash`.

Answer (score 5):

There are several issues with your code:

1. If you specify `/bin/sh` as the she-bang, then you should write your script in `sh` syntax (that is POSIX `sh` syntax or Bourne shell syntax if you plan to be portable to very old systems). There's no `shopts` in `sh` syntax (`shopts` is `bash` specific), nor `[[ ... ]]` (which is a `ksh` construct also available in `zsh` and `bash`), nor `local`, nor `let`.

   Basically, your script would only work with `bash`, so you should either use a `#! /bin/bash -` she-bang (but then your script wouldn't work on systems where `bash` is not installed), or convert it to `sh` syntax.
2. Leaving a variable unquoted in list context such as in arguments to a command (like `basename $file`) is the split+glob operator. You don't want to do that here.
3. When passing arbitrary data to a command, you've got to use `--` to separate the arguments from the options. Otherwise a filename starting with `-` would be taken as an option. So: `bn=$(basename -- "$file")`
4. There's a confusion regarding `-d` and `-f` common with people coming from the Microsoft word. In Unix, everything (most things) is a file. There are many different types of files: directories, symlinks, regular files, fifos, sockets, devices, and many others depending on the actual Unix variant.

   `[[ -d ... ]]` returns true if the file is of type directory, `[[ -f ... ]]` if the file is of type *regular*. What about the other types of files? Also in case of symlinks `[[ -d ... ]]` returns true if the file is of type symlinks but eventually resolves to a file of type *directory*. What that means is that if for instance, there's a symlink pointing to `/` in there, your script will loop indefinitely.

   It would be as if using `find -L` (formerly, `find -follow`) except that `find -L` is able to detect loops. For the same reason, you cannot use `bash`'s `globstar` (though you could use `zsh` or `ksh93` equivalent which don't have the same problem) unless your `bash` is version 4.3 or above.

   So, do you want to consider directory versus non-directory files? Or *directory* and *regular* files only, ignoring all the rest?

   In the first case, to test for directory, it's `[ -d "$file" ] && [ ! -L "$file" ]`, and for non-directory: `[ -L "$file" ] || [ ! -d "$file" ]`.

   In the second case: `[ -d "$file" ] && [ ! -L "$file" ]` and `[ -f "$file" ] && [ ! -L "$file" ]`.
5. It should be noted that you count directory entries more than files. For example, if a file appears as two different directory entries (two hardlinks), it will be counted twice. There are also two directory entries that you're not counting: `.` and `..` (though you probably don't want to count them).
6. The `[` command or the `[[ ... ]]` construct and shell globbing don't report an error when they can't access a file (for lack or permission or because the file doesn't exist or path components are not directories), so there will be cases where you'll get the wrong number but won't get an error message telling you why. To work around that, you could check for read and search access to directories and report errors accordingly.
7. The `[[ ... == pattern ]]` operator expects a filename/wildcard pattern, not a regular expression. In Bourne/POSIX `sh` syntax, you'd use a `case` statement for that. The wildcard equivalent of `^\.` is `.*`, but here, you're matching against the full path, so that would be (as regex): `/\.[^/]*$`, which you can't convert to wildcard pattern unless you use `ksh` extended pattern.

   Instead, you can use:

   ```
   case ${fil##*/} in
     (.*) ...
   esac
   ```

   in POSIX `sh` syntax.

So, with all that in mind, you could write it instead (in POSIX `sh` syntax):

```
hiddenDirs=0 hiddenNonDirs=0 dirs=0 nonDirs=0
isDir() {
  [ -d "$1" ] && [ ! -L "$1" ]
}
isHidden() {
  case ${1##*/} in
    (.*) return 0
  esac
  return 1
}
listAllFiles() {
  for f do
    ls -ld -- "$f" || continue
    if isDir "$f"; then
      if isHidden "$f"; then
        hiddenDirs=$(($hiddenDirs + 1))
      else
        dirs=$(($dirs + 1))
      fi
      if [ ! -r "$f" ]; then
        printf >&2 'Error: %s directory not readable\n' "$f"
        continue
      fi
      if [ ! -x "$f" ]; then
        printf >&2 'Error: %s directory not searchable\n' "$f"
        continue
      fi
      set -- "$f"/[*] "$f"/*
      if [ "$#" -eq 2 ] &&  [ "$1" != "$2" ]; then
        shift 2
      else
        shift
      fi
      n=$#
      set -- "$f"/.[*] "$f"/.* "$@"
      if [ "$(($# - $n))" -eq 2 ] &&  [ "$1" != "$2" ]; then
        shift 2
      else
        shift
        for f do
          case ${f##*/} in
            (.|..) ;;
            (*) set -- "$@" "$f"
          esac
          shift
        done
      fi
      listAllFiles "$@"
    else
      if isHidden "$f"; then
        hiddenNonDirs=$(($hiddenNonDirs + 1))
      else
        nonDirs=$(($nonDirs + 1))
      fi
    fi
  done
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer. Very informative.

Answer (score 0):

To locate the dot files `basename` must be applied to the $file variable.
e.g. A path `/tmp/.dotone` for example does not have a first character of '.'

The code extract uses `basename` to assign the variable `f` with the file name, then subsequently uses `${f:0:1}` to locate the first character and compare that with '.'.

```
for file in "$dir"/*; do
    f=$(basename $file)
     if [[ $bn == .* ]]; then
     let hiddenDirectoryCounter+=1
     listAllFiles "$file"
   elif [[ -f $file &&  "${f:0:1}" = '.' ]]; then
     ls -l $file
     let hiddenFileCounter+=1
   elif [[ -f $file ]];then
       ...
       ...
```

Comment: This still returns hidden files as 0, sorry

Comment: this works on bash OS X